# Bluetooth Programming with the MSP-EXP432P401R

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, hc-05, msp432

I am trying to connect my MSP432 to my HC-05 Bluetooth module however when I connect to the module using a Bluetooth terminal, I receive no feedback. I've attached my code as well. Is the RX pin P3.2 and TX P3.3?

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); /* Define baud rate for serial communication */
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  
    if (Serial.available())  /* If data is available on serial port */
    {
      char data_received; 
      data_received = Serial.read();  /* Data received from bluetooth */
      if (data_received == '1')
      {
        digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
        Serial.write("LED turned ON");        
      }
      else if (data_received == '2')
      {
        digitalWrite(12, LOW);
        Serial.write("LED turned OFF");
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.write("Select either 1 or 2");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what did the datasheet for the board and chip show with respect to the tx/rx pins?

Comment: The datasheet shows those pins as the correct TX and RX pins but not sure. here is a link to it: https://energia.nu/pinmaps/msp-exp432p401r/